# Combining WPF Xbap app with MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wpf, xbap

I have MVC application. In one of the views I need to show or return a light weight WPF xbap page (running in IE or Firefox).

What will be the best approach to combine these two technologies in one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to create 1 extra project with WPF XPAB and just attach like sub-project under IIS to the primary one and refer to that page.